# Pointwise bounded and uniformly bounded sequence of operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Consider the subspace $V=\{(x_i)\in l^2 : \sum_{i=1}^ \infty |x_i| < \infty\}$ of the hilbert space $l^2$ of all square summable real  sequences. For $n \in \mathbb N$, define $T_n : V \in \mathbb R$ by $T_n((x_k)))= \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.
Consider the following statements:

(P) : $\{T_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is pointwise bounded on $V$

(Q) : $\{T_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ is uniformly bounded on $\{x \in V : ||x||_2=1\}$

It's obvious that $P$ is true

I want to disprove $Q$. If $||x_2||=1 $ and $x \in V$ then $T_n$ should be bounded by $1$.
please help where am i wrong ?

Comment: $V$ is the entire space $\ell^2$?

Comment: You're not wrong, as you state these P,Q here $(P)$ is false. Not just that, but $(Q)$ is also false, because you can take again $x=(x_k)=(1/k)$ and then take $y=\frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Then $T_n(y)\to\infty$ so these are not even pointwise bounded on the unit sphere

Comment: V is not entire space. I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, $V$ is not a closed subspace of $\ell^2$, since if $x_n=(1,\frac{1}{2},\dots,\frac{1}{n},0,0,0,\dots,)$ we have $(x_n)\subset V$ and if $x=(\frac{1}{k})_{k=1}^\infty\in\ell^2$ then $\|x_n-x\|_2^2=\sum_{k\ge n+1}\frac{1}{k^2}\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. But $x\not\in V$ obviously.

Obviously $(P)$ is true as OP says so. For $(Q)$ take the above elements $x_n$ that I mentioned and scale them to have norm $1$, so set $y_m=\frac{x_m}{\|x_m\|_2}\in\{z\in V:\|z\|_2=1\}$. Then $T_n(y_n)=\frac{1}{\|x_n\|_2}\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}$. But $\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{j}\to\infty$ while $\frac{1}{\|x_n\|_2}\to\frac{1}{\|x\|_2}<\infty$, so $T_n(y_n)\to\infty$. Since $\{T_n(y_n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset\{T_n(x):n\in\mathbb{N},x\in\{z\in V:\|z\|_2=1\}\}$, we see that the set is not uniformly bounded.